# Creating Dynamic marker groups in Leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 layers.group3 = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
 layers.group3.clearLayers();

 map.addLayer(layers.group3);
```

Also i first need to check if the layer already exists when i call the method again to add/remove markers it seems the hasLayer is not working

Answer (score 0):

> like for example "map.addLayer(markers, "group1markers")" ????

No: Leaflet doesn't support naming layers in that way, regardless of what plugin you use: the key is using variables correctly. You can keep your own index of layers, though, like:

```
var layers = {};
layers.group1markers = group1markers;
map.addLayer(markers);
```

Likewise, `hasLayer`, as in [the Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-haslayer) takes a layer object as an argument, not a variable name as a string.

Comment: firstly thanks for you reply, I have tried to achieve my goal from what you said on using the variables correctly. you can see my edited code above in the initial question. However I am still struggling - i created 3 different groups, the group 3 is the one that is drawing the markers but still i do not know how to set the name it. The name comes from var t parameter. I am not very good with JavaScript.